# attr_accessible in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attr-accessible

I'm doing the onemonth rails and I'v got a problem with the attr_accessible function. I've installed it as a gem in rails 4(gem 'protected_attributes') and using it with the simple_form.

But the problem is that when I update my form with a name, it doesnt remember it! But it says it updated successfully??

Ths is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name
end
```

Comment: remove the entire line of `attr_accessible` and use strong parameters in your user controller

Comment: I generated the users controller, but I don't understand what I have to put in it, to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `Devise` you can remove the entire `attr_accessible` line (and the `strong_parameters` gem, see more below). Devise provides [a controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)  which handles sign-up for you already.

If you want to add other attributes to your user you can subclass `Devise::RegistrationsController` with your custom controller:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

You then need to tell Devise to route to your custom controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

**PS**. I would also recommend removing the `strong_parameters` gem and use the out of the box [Rails 4 strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). There are several known problems with whitelisting parameters on the model level (different params for different actions for example).

Comment: Also here is an [example of an app](https://github.com/remote-wind/remote-wind) which uses Devise and simple_form.

Comment: you said that devise  provides the controller, but I cant find it under /devise / app / controllers / devise / registrations_controller.rb/ do I have to generate it myself ou did I miss something? Tnx Tom

Comment: Yes, but it is in the Devise gem - not in your application code. You can find the location by running `gem which devise`.

Comment: Tnx man, I did just that and it worked:) I generated the controlelr and made the route to it!